# Can I display last actions of everyone in the Django Admin index?

Tags: django, django-admin

Is there a way to display every last actions made in the Django admin? By default the admin display only last actions of the current user but I would like to see last actions of every administrators. Since **I don't have any code of this page in my project**, how can I interact with this widget? Should I override the whole index?

I would like to get something like this:

[image: Result expected in the admin interface]

instead of just the 2 first entries if I'm connected as `er****` (according to the screen).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, it is. Everything in the Django admin is **customizable by overriding the template**. All you need is to override the file [`templates/admin/index.html` of your current Django version](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/contrib/admin/templates/admin/index.html) and change this line:

```
{% get_admin_log 10 as admin_log for_user user %}
```

and remove the `for_user user` part. It will display the 10 last recent actions, without filtering by user. To be perfect, you also need to change the name of the block and add action author. The sidebar block should be something like:

```
{% block sidebar %}
<div id="content-related">
    <div class="module" id="recent-actions-module">
        <h2>{% trans 'Recent Actions' %}</h2>
        <h3>{% trans 'Last Actions' %}</h3>             {# Title modified #}
            {% load log %}
            {% get_admin_log 10 as admin_log %}         {# No more filtering #}
            {% if not admin_log %}
            <p>{% trans 'None available' %}</p>
            {% else %}
            <ul class="actionlist">
            {% for entry in admin_log %}
            <li class="{% if entry.is_addition %}addlink{% endif %}{% if entry.is_change %}changelink{% endif %}{% if entry.is_deletion %}deletelink{% endif %}">
                {% if entry.is_deletion or not entry.get_admin_url %}
                    {{ entry.object_repr }}
                {% else %}
                    <a href="{{ entry.get_admin_url }}">{{ entry.object_repr }}</a>
                {% endif %}
                <br/>
                {% if entry.content_type %}
                    {# Add the author here, at the end #}
                    <span class="mini quiet">{% filter capfirst %}{% trans entry.content_type.name %}{% endfilter %}, by {{ entry.user }}</span>    
                {% else %}
                    <span class="mini quiet">{% trans 'Unknown content' %}</span>
                {% endif %}
            </li>
            {% endfor %}
            </ul>
            {% endif %}
    </div>
</div>
{% endblock %}
```

Answer (score 5):

This is very easy to override on django 1.9:

In your master `urls.py` where the admin interface is loaded (with `admin.autodiscover()`), overwrite the name of the admin index template file:

```
from django.contrib import admin
admin.site.index_template = 'admin/my_custom_index.html'
admin.autodiscover()
```

Then create the file `admin\my_custom_index.html` inside any application's template directory (eg. `\my_app\templates\admin\my_custom_index.html`). It can extend the existing template, so does not need to be that lengthy:

```
{% extends "admin/index.html" %}
{% load i18n static %}

{% block sidebar %}
<div id="content-related">
    <div class="module" id="recent-actions-module">
        <h2>{% trans 'Recent actions' %}</h2>
        <h3>{% trans 'All users' %}</h3>
            {% load log %}
            {% get_admin_log 30 as admin_log %}
            {% if not admin_log %}
            <p>{% trans 'None available' %}</p>
            {% else %}
            <ul class="actionlist">
            {% for entry in admin_log %}
            <li class="{% if entry.is_addition %}addlink{% endif %}{% if entry.is_change %}changelink{% endif %}{% if entry.is_deletion %}deletelink{% endif %}">
                {% if entry.is_deletion or not entry.get_admin_url %}
                    {{ entry.object_repr }}
                {% else %}
                    <a href="{{ entry.get_admin_url }}">{{ entry.object_repr }}</a>
                {% endif %}
                <br/>
                {% if entry.content_type %}
                    <span class="mini quiet">{% filter capfirst %}{{ entry.content_type }}{% endfilter %}, by {{ entry.user }}</span>
                {% else %}
                    <span class="mini quiet">{% trans 'Unknown content' %}</span>
                {% endif %}
            </li>
            {% endfor %}
            </ul>
            {% endif %}
    </div>
</div>
{% endblock %}
```

The block has varied in django over the years, the version here is newer than that in Maximime's answer.